# angular Ui grid aggregation value

Tags: angular, angular-ui-grid

hi  i am working on angular  ui grid for an about couple of days 
And   now my  is question is that if the sum of total is negative then the color of that particular footer must be in red color

```
examples total= -50000

-5000 must be in red color  and remaining colors must be asusual
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cellClass` property of the column in the column defs. This property can take either a static class name or a function.
For example (taken from: http://brianhann.com/customize-ui-grid-with-dynamic-cell-classes/):

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  enableSorting: true,
  columnDefs: [
    { field: 'name' },
    { field: 'gender',
      cellClass: function(grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex) {
        if (grid.getCellValue(row ,col).toLowerCase() === 'male') {
          return 'red';
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};
```